# Is the word order of this sentence correct?

Tags: word-order

I came across such a sentence in OED.

> They got in disguised as security guards.

I'm wondering, whether or not the above sentence can be rephrased into
"Disguised as security guards, they got in", without change of meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both sentences are correct and have the same meaning.

The second option, for me, adds some emphasis on the fact that they were disguised as guards.

Comment: I agree they have the same meaning though in different context the rephrase might sound weird. As a response to the question "how did they get in?" only Yoda would respond "disguised as security guards, they got in."

Comment: "They knew it would be difficult to gain access to [the place] but, disguised as security guards, they got in". Not very natural - we would be more likely to say _by disguising themselves as security guards_.